# facing issue while formating the JSON Data

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON which i am formatting to render my html table

- i have a JSON having `Array` inside which there are `Objects`
- My JSON is having data with `billdatewise` and `outletwise`
- now the issue is i have several outlets but on some dates that outlets have no data,so i want to show 0 when there is no data for that outlet

**my code**

```js
var cpy = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "Total": 511153,
    "cash": 490289,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 20864,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "Total": 115704,
    "cash": 112854,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 2850,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "Total": 83597,
    "cash": 83597,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "Total": 167421,
    "cash": 167421,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",  //here for billdate 2018-09-03 i don't have data for malleshwaram so i want to have output as 0 when i am formating the json
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "Total": 53775,
    "cash": 53775,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  }
]



function getDataList(jsn) {
  var billdate = [];
  var outlet = [];
  var SalesType = [];

  billdate = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.billdate))];
  outlet = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.outlet))];
  for (let i in jsn[0]) {
    if (i !== 'billdate' && i !== 'outlet') {
      SalesType.push(i)
    }
  }

  return {
    billdate,
    outlet,
    SalesType
  }

}


function structureJSON(obj) {
  console.log("billdarte :-" + obj.billdate)
  var arr = [];
  obj.billdate.forEach((ele1, index1) => {

    obj.SalesType.forEach((ele, index) => {
      let row;
      if (index === 0) {
        row = {
          billdate: ele1,
          SalesType: ele
        };
      } else {
        row = {
          billdate: "",
          SalesType: ele
        };
      }
      obj.outlet.forEach((ele2, index2) => {
        var selected = cpy.filter((ele3, index3) => {
          return ele3.billdate === ele1 && ele3.outlet === ele2
        });

        row[ele2] = selected[0][ele]
      })
      arr.push(row)
    })

  })

  return arr;

}
var tableValue = structureJSON(getDataList(cpy))
console.log(tableValue)
```

**Key points**

1. In my above code i have data for `billdate` 2018-09-02 to 2018-09-03
2. for billdate 2018-09-02 all `outlets` are there i.e `Jayanagar` , `Malleshwaram` and `Kolar`
3. but on billdate 2018-09-03 there is no sale in `Malleshwaram` so object of `malleshwaram` is missing from the billdate 2018-09-03
4. What i am trying to do is when there is no data for the outlet on that date it should display that object as 0
5. My expected output is

`[
              {
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "SalesType": "Total",
                "JAYANAGAR": "511153",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "115704",
                "KOLAR": "83597"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "cash",
                "JAYANAGAR": "490289",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "112854",
                "KOLAR": "83597"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "creditcard",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "coupon",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "paytm",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "credit",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "swiggy",
                "JAYANAGAR": "20864",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "2850",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "kb",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "bigbasket",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                "SalesType": "Total",
                "JAYANAGAR": "167421",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",    // this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "53775"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "cash",
                "JAYANAGAR": "167421",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "53775"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "creditcard",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "coupon",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "paytm",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "credit",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "swiggy",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "kb",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              },
              {
                "billdate": "",
                "SalesType": "bigbasket",
                "JAYANAGAR": "0",
                "MALLESHWARAM": "0",// this malleshwaram should be 0
                "KOLAR": "0"
              }
            ]`

as of now what is inmy mind is that i have to check `obj.Total`  when i am parsing
like `obj.Total?obj.Total:0`

but don't know how to implement that
I have fully explained my issue if any doubts are there please ask me,i am stuck here from a while now
i am already creating array of unique `outlets`

Please guys anybody help

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your json, but imo Total doesn't matter. What matters is if you have a total outlet count (in your example you know the total is 3: JAYNAGAR, MALLESHWARAM and KOLAR). If you know the total outlets then you can simply notice that a certain billdate has an outlet missing and fill that info with 0's

Comment: I would probably use the  obj.outlet.forEach() in the beggining to count the number of outlets, and from then just check if each date has the total outlets intended. (Beware of duplicates though!)

Comment: @H.Figueiredo you are right i have to check first how many outlet are there,can you help me with some code please, and all the outlet and billdate are dynamic

Comment: You can simply pluck all outlets like this :
`let outlets = cpy.map(obj => obj.outlet);`
Then you can find unique outlets if needed

Comment: @Ninad a small piece of code with mine can be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think this is what you intended:

```js
function countOutlets(obj)
{
   let objUnique= obj.outlet.filter(function(item, index){
      return obj.outlet.indexOf(item) >= index;
  });
  return objUnique
}
var cpy = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "Total": 511153,
    "cash": 490289,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 20864,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "Total": 115704,
    "cash": 112854,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 2850,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "Total": 83597,
    "cash": 83597,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "Total": 167421,
    "cash": 167421,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",  //here for billdate 2018-09-03 i don't have data for malleshwaram so i want to have output as 0 when i am formating the json
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "Total": 53775,
    "cash": 53775,
    "creditcard": 0,
    "coupon": 0,
    "paytm": 0,
    "credit": 0,
    "swiggy": 0,
    "kb": 0,
    "bigbasket": 0
  }
]



function getDataList(jsn) {
  var billdate = [];
  var outlet = [];
  var SalesType = [];

  billdate = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.billdate))];
  outlet = [...new Set(jsn.map(ele => ele.outlet))];
  for (let i in jsn[0]) {
    if (i !== 'billdate' && i !== 'outlet') {
      SalesType.push(i)
    }
  }

  return {
    billdate,
    outlet,
    SalesType
  }

}
function structureJSON(obj) {
  let alloutlets=countOutlets(getDataList(cpy))
  console.log("billdarte :-" + obj.billdate)
  var arr = [];
  obj.billdate.forEach((ele1, index1) => {

    obj.SalesType.forEach((ele, index) => {
      let row;
      if (index === 0) {
        row = {
          billdate: ele1,
          SalesType: ele
        };
      } else {
        row = {
          billdate: "",
          SalesType: ele
        };
      }
      alloutlets.forEach((ele2, index2) => {
        var selected = cpy.filter((ele3, index3) => {
          return ele3.billdate === ele1 && ele3.outlet == ele2
        });
        if(selected.length!=0)
        row[ele2] = selected[0][ele]
        else
         row[ele2] = "0";
      })
      arr.push(row)
    })

  })

  return arr;

}
var tableValue = structureJSON(getDataList(cpy))
console.log(tableValue)
```

I realize my countOutlets is kinda redundant, but by the time I realized it, I already had made it.

Hope this helps.